# AngularJS validations in .NET CSHTML files

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

My angularjs validation in .NET MVC cshtml files isnt working.

Below is my code:

cshtml code:

```
<div id="addEditItem" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <form novalidate role="form" name="frmItem">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Item Details</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" ng-model="id">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="name" maxlength="50" ng-required="true">
                        <span style="color:red" class="help-block" ng-if="frmItem.name.$error.required && frmItem.name.$dirty">*</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="SaveItem()"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller Code:

```
medApp.controller("itemController", function ($scope, itemService) {

    $scope.SaveItem = function () {
        var itemModel = {
            Id: $scope.id,
            Name: $scope.name,
            Description: $scope.description,
            Manufacturer: $scope.manufacturer,
            BatchNo: $scope.batchNo,
            ExpiryDate: $scope.expiryDate
        };
        if (!CheckIsValid()) {
            alert('Please fill the detail!');
            return false;
        }
        var requestResponse = itemService.AddEdit(itemModel);
        Message(requestResponse);
    };



    function CheckIsValid() {
        var isValid = true;
        if ($('#name').val() === '' || $('#description').val() === '' || $('#manufacturer').val() === '' || $('#batchNo').val() === '') {
            isValid = false;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
});
```

The addEditItem is a modal dialog. If I click on submit the alert('Error in getting records'); is shown.
I want the validation to happen at cshtml level rather than the java alert.

I am going to remove the CheckIsValid function. I want the validation to happen only in cshtml file.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: do you declare app and controller in your view ?

Comment: Yes I did. The app name is medApp and its in _Layout file. <div ng-app="medApp" class="container body-content">  and controller is in the view file <div ng-controller="itemController">

Answer (score 1):

In your attached cshtml code I could find the "name" id only, but your check function is also checking"description", "manufacturer" and "batchNo". All of those item must be exist otherwise the function returns with false.
The CheckIsValid() function will return true when all items exists and contains at least one character. Anyway the good start is to put a breakpoint into your check code and see why returns with false.

Comment: I am going to remove the CheckIsValid function. My question is its not validating in cshtml file before coming to angular controller.

Comment: Okay, sorry. Anyway why don't you set the submit button disabled if the `frmItem.name.$error.required` is true? I mean if you want a simple checking (exist value or not) the ng-required is enough. If you want to create a more complex validation the you have to write your custom validator directive on angular side.

Comment: @Jester .. I am not looking at any complicated custom validator. Its just the way it works in .NET razor engine UI. You add a required validator and that's it!! Is it not possible in angularJS being used in cshtml?

Answer (score 1):

Wordking [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLpkxmya/)

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" ng-model="id">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="name" maxlength="50" ng-required="true">
        <span style="color:red" class="help-block" ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required && !myForm.name.$valid">*</span>
    </div>
<button ng-click="display()">Log</button>
</form>
```

Would like to add that you need to add:

- Use name on inputs to be accesable from the scope
- Use ng-show/ng-hide for validation since it changes alot

Comment: I'll try this code and let you know. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I tried the code. Its still hitting the display() function in angular controller. I also added the ng-controller to the form but still its the same.

Comment: Why do you have the modal dialog inside the form? any special reason?

Comment: @Jester...no reason for having a modal inside a form. Do you have a different suggestion?

Comment: in angular js you can have a seperate template for modal and use Bootstrap modal support or such. If you look at my sample there is no modal